# laravel project, npm install does not work (latest ver. Node, NPM, win7 x86)

Tags: laravel, node-gyp

After I run the command **npm install** (elevated cmd) I got this problem:

*npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'*

**node node-gyp** command also does not work for obvious reasons.

I am wondering is there any way manually to install node-gyp. Because using npm install node-gyp@latest does not work either.

Why?

I am trying to build a simple chatroom(Laravel + Vue.js) following the steps explained in a video tutorial and I need to use the command **npm run dev**, but before that **npm install**.

I've read at least 6 topics about these and tried the following:

1. Downloaded the latest version of NPM and Node, which solved the problem with 
   ENOENT, open package.json
2. Changed the permissions of my node_modules folder inside my Laravel project 
   to full control
3. Followed the instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp, also have 
   .NET Framework 4.5.2

I am new to this, so if you can explain me like I'm five how can I make my npm download all the stuff I need(Vue, Lodash, laravel-mix, bootstrap) it will be great.

Comment: I had the same issue and I ended up using yarn.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yarn did the job!